# Plot scatterplots with errors in a colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar, errorbar

I have a dataset with

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,3,4,5,6]
z = [4,5,6,7,8]
x_err = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2]
y_err = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2]]
```

I want to plot (x,y,x_err,y_err) with colorbar of z (Want to see x&y variations with respect to z). I cannot plot errors in plt.scatter() and I am not able to plot colorbars in plt.errorbar().

Need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an importable matplotlib library to help you here is a example that your variables can be worked into;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('_mpl-gallery')

# make the data
np.random.seed(3)
x = 4 + np.random.normal(0, 2, 24)
y = 4 + np.random.normal(0, 2, len(x))
# size and color:
sizes = np.random.uniform(15, 80, len(x))
colors = np.random.uniform(15, 80, len(x))

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(x, y, s=sizes, c=colors, vmin=0, vmax=100)

ax.set(xlim=(0, 8), xticks=np.arange(1, 8),
   ylim=(0, 8), yticks=np.arange(1, 8))

plt.show()
```

[Use matplotlib to help you](https://matplotlib.org/)